# Bigcommerce - Posting Products to the API

Tags: xml, api, e-commerce, bigcommerce

I am trying to post a product to my bigcommerce staging area. The BC api response has thus far been helpful in pointing out why my XML schema was not compliant but now it only returns a 500 error.

```
<product>
 <name>xbox</name>
 <type>physical</type>
 <description>this is a test item</description>
 <price>499.99</price>
 <categories>
  <categories>18</categories>
 </categories>
 <availability>available</availability>
 <weight>0.5</weight>
</product>
```

Since the api has successfully parsed my xml to point out errors I am sure that my headers are correct (applicaiton/xml) and the error itself is a 500 error with the message "**An error occurred processing the request**"

I have consulted the [BC Api page](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products) for this procedure and even gone as far as to mimic the json object they provide.

```
{
"name": "xbox",
"type": "physical",
"description": "this is a test item",
"price": "499.99",
"categories": { "categories": "18" },
"availability": "available",
"weight": "0.5"
```

}

The json above posted just fine (after changing my header to application/json). For the life of me why is the XML not going through? I have posted customers and orders through BC with relatively no problem but this is bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when posting products to BigCommerce.  The solution I found was very simple.  When posting a product with only one category, the category must be included twice.  I have no idea why, but that's what made it work for me.

```
<product>
 <name>xbox</name>
 <type>physical</type>
 <description>this is a test item</description>
 <price>499.99</price>
 <categories>
   <category>18</category>
   <category>18</category>
 </categories>
 <availability>available</availability>
 <weight>0.5</weight>
</product>
```

Be sure to use "category" as your element name inside the "categories" array.

UPDATE:  I just realized that I didn't include the JSON format, which is what you're working with.  It's simpler.

```
"categories" : [ 18, 18],
```

Be sure to use square brackets.

Comment: That's strange, I haven't seen that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is how you have your category data. Try using value instead of categories within the categories array.

```
<product>
 <name>xbox</name>
 <type>physical</type>
 <description>this is a test item</description>
 <price>499.99</price>
 <categories>
  <value>18</value>
 </categories>
 <availability>available</availability>
 <weight>0.5</weight>
</product>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting of the categories section is incorrect, it should be an array of numbers.

```
{
    "name": "xbox",
    "type": "physical",
    "description": "this is a test item",
    "price": "499.99",
    "categories": [ 18 ],
    "availability": "available",
    "weight": "0.5"
}
```

Perhaps there is a typo in the docs.